# How can I limit the amount of files watched by lsp-mode?

Tags: lsp-mode

With lsp-mode, I'm getting

```
Watching all the files in /foo would require adding watches to 3792 directories, so watching the repo may slow Emacs down.
Do you want to watch all files in /foo? (y or n) n
```

How can I set maximum or how can I disable being asked this question?;)  f

Comment: You'll just have to try it: the limit will depend on a host of factors, in particular the "heft" of your machine, but it may also depend on the complexity of your directory tree. I would answer `y` and see how bad it is: it may not be bad at all. If it is, then I would bisect to try to find the sweet spot: use 2048 (about half) - if that's bad, halve it again; if it's OK, try 3/2*2048 - and so on. Be systematic.

Comment: Right, but one can say if 5000 directories is overkill. Also, how can I change the number once I've set a number?;)

Comment: "one can say if 5000 directories is overkill" - not without testing. On the other question, no idea.

Comment: It depends on the platform as well: on some a file descriptor is consumed for every file watched, on some it's one for every directory, and on some it's zero.

Comment: Can someone at least provide hints on the easiest way to recover if things bog down? Do I just need to close the files involved? Or stop some processes? or ?? I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 with 32 GB RAM, FWIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My pleasure;)

(setq lsp-file-watch-threshold 5000)